# Understanding DNS - Setting Up DNS in Namecheap and Route 53?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, routes

What happens when you:

1. Buy a domain from Namecheap
2. set up your domain's DNS records inside Namecheap
3. Create a Route53 hosting group in AWS for the same domain
4. Set up DNS records for the same domain/subdomains, but this time inside Route 53?

Which configuration will work?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45477247/1145196) shed any light?

Answer (score 3):

Your domain name configuration at Namecheap would still be pointing to the Namecheap Domain Name Servers (DNS), so only your DNS configuration at Namecheap would be in use. The configuration in Route53 would not be visible to anyone making domain name queries on the Internet. You can only have one set of active name servers associated with your domain, so you would have to pick between using the Namecheap domain name servers or the Route53 domain name servers.

Comment: Hi Mark, do you mind to elaborate the *configuration in Route53 would not be visible to anyone making domain name queries on the internet* part? I'm learning about server and seems that when we do a dns check, every dns records show. Are there any significant difference between the DNS hosting service between NC and AWS other than the convenience tied with using AWS products and services if handled by AWS. Thanks

Comment: @Jalene in the original question, they had setup DNS entries in two separate DNS services. You can only have one "source of truth", and in this case that was Namecheap, because they hadn't actually pointed their DNS hosting to Route53 yet. So those DNS settings in Route53 were just records sitting in their AWS account that were not in use. When someone queried for the DNS resolution of the domain, they would have received the Namecheap records, not the Route53 records, thus my comment that the Route53 records were not visible to anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Once you point the NS records to AWS Name servers, only than AWS Route53 configuration will work, until than NameCheap DNS settings will work.