# DNS Records and Nameservers

Tags: dns, web-hosting, nameservers

When I deploy my website on Google App Engine and add a custom domain(that I own from GoDaddy.com or name.com or namecheap.com etc.), GAE provides me with **A, AAAA, and CNAME** records which I need to add in the DNS record configuration in GoDaddy.com/name.com/namecheap.com website.

Similarly, When I deploy my website on Digitalocean and add a custom domain(that I own from GoDaddy.com or name.com or namecheap.com etc.), it provides me with **nameservers**(ns1.digitalocean.com,ns2.digitalocean.com etc.) which I need to add in the Nameserver configuration in GoDaddy.com/name.com/namecheap.com website.

So is adding nameservers equivalent to setting DNS records?

Comment: Answer to similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45477247/1145196

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So is adding nameservers equivalent to setting DNS records?

Well, yes and no.

Yes, the "Nameservers" setting actually creates 'NS' type records in DNS – except they are *not* in your zone; they are in the *parent* zone. For example, if your domain is `example.com`, then its nameserver addresses must be known by the `com` zone.

(That said, your own zone *also* has identical 'NS' records, but they're not the ones that really matter.)

But on the other hand, no, setting nameservers (NS records) has a *completely different purpose* from creating A/AAAA type records. An 'A' record directly points to the server where a website is hosted, while an 'NS' record *adds indirection* – the 'NS' record points to a server which holds the 'A' records.

> Can you tell me the complete flow of what happens including DNS and zone file lookup that take place when I type "www.example.com".

2. Your OS (which has a 'stub' resolver) sends the query to a 'full' or 'recursive' resolver.
3. The recursive resolver has a built-in list of nameserver addresses for "" (the DNS root).
4. The resolver sends the query to the root nameservers, receives a referral to the "com" domain's nameservers ("I don't have that record, but I do have com./NS records").
5. The resolver sends the same query to the 'com' nameservers, again receives a referral to the "example.com" domain's nameservers.
6. The resolver sends the same query to the 'example.com' nameservers, and finally receives the actual answer.
7. The recursive resolver returns the answer to you.

See existing documentation:

- https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/dns/dns-server-types/
- https://royal.pingdom.com/a-visual-explanation-of-how-dns-lookups-work-2/

Comment: So when I deploy my website on Google App Engine and instead of updating the A, AAAA, CNAME records(given by GAE) in Namecheap website, I update the nameservers in Namecheap website with GAE nameservers then also my website would work fine? _As now the nameservers in the namecheap website will point to the server containing the A, AAAA, CNAME records i.e GAE_

Comment: Usually nameserver hosting is an independent service and it doesn't matter whether your A/AAAA records are hosted by Namecheap or by Google, as long as they exist and of course _point to_ the correct server. (Only few rare exceptions: CDNs like Cloudflare.)